# Datum transformation with velocity corrections

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, georeferencing, datum

I have a coordinates with velocity values of some points in ITRF2014 at 2010.0 epoch and I want to convert these coordinates to ITRF96 1998.0 epoch.

I apply the velocity corrections to my coordinates before apply transformation to ITRF96.

```
X(t) = X(t0) + Vx * (t-t0) % to X coordinate , x(t0) i ITRF2014
```

I used the formula as above, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

I used MJD values and then divided the (t-t0) by 365.25:

```
t = 1998 ---  MJD = 50814
t0 = 2010 --- MJD = 55197

(T-T0) = (50814-55197)/365.25
```

Is it correct to do the velocity correction this way? Is my use of time correct?

Comment: I'd say that depends on the units of speed that the velocities are expressed in, just make sure to use the same units, or convert units if needed. What are the units in this case?